# HTTP GET response with a modified identifier

Tags: rest, http

I have a http get rest api contract as follows,

```
/car/1
{
"id": 1,
"color": "blue"
}
```

However, after some migration, the identifier of cars has changed to uuids. 
When i get the same request as before, how do i respond with

```
{
"id": "uuid",
"color": "blue"
}
```

Comment: Well, this totally depends on the language and frameworks you have used to build your server. And I don't understand why you wanna send the parameters you're getting from your request back in the response.

Comment: @YohanE not really. HTTP & REST are language independent abstractions/protocols for exchange of data between systems typically over a network. the id is the resource identifier.